# Pick a record based on a given value in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in postgres like below,

```
alg_campaignid | alg_score |   cp    |   sum    
----------------+-----------+---------+----------
           9829 |  30.44056 | 12.4000 |  12.4000
           9880 |  29.59280 | 12.0600 |  24.4600
           9882 |  29.59280 | 12.0600 |  36.5200
           9827 |  29.27504 | 11.9300 |  48.4500
           9821 |  29.14840 | 11.8800 |  60.3300
           9881 |  29.14840 | 11.8800 |  72.2100
           9883 |  29.14840 | 11.8800 |  84.0900
          10026 |  28.79280 | 11.7300 |  95.8200
          10680 |  10.31504 |  4.1800 | 100.0000
```

From which i have to select a record based on randomly generated number from 0 to 100.i.e first record should be returned if random number picked is between 0 and 12.4000,second if rendom is between 12.4000 and 24.4600,and likewise last if random no is between 95.8200 and 100.0000.

For Example 
if the random number picked is 8 then the first record should be returned
or
if the random number picked is 48 then the fourth record should be returned

Is it possible to do this postgres if so kindly recommend a solution for this..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in Postgres.  If you want to generate the number in the database:

```
with r as (
      select random() * 100 as r
     )
select t.*
from table t cross join r
where t.sum <= r.r
order by t.sum desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: this one always returns me 1st row and if i remove limit 1 it returns all records till the random value